# Can't select row in a "Table" for a custom Plugin

Tags: sitecore-commerce

I created a custom plugin for Commerce Business Tools. Added 2 Buttons (actions) in it `Add` And `Update`. When clicking On Add it inserts a row and view is showing all the rows added.

I used  `UIHint = "Table"` in `EntityView` to get the rows in a table. Now I want to select a row and update that row using `Update` button just like Promotions does.

The problem is I'm not able to select row from table. I thought that should have been default functionality of the `UIHint = "Table"` to be able to select row just like `List`. But I don't want to use `List`.

Please can anybody help me on this. Any suggestions on how to implement that?

Comment: Can you compare the json you are receiving for your custom view you have created with the json from the promotions sections you are referring and see if there are any differences?

Comment: @Vipin can't see anything obvious.

Comment: is your first row coming as selected on load? and can you check that for each row  there is a child view and each child view has an ItemId property that should have some value.

Comment: Yes the first row was selected. I corrected ItemId to have unique value for each child view and now I can select a Row. Thanks for your help Vipin. My next question was how to get that selected row while editing. Does it have any event where I can store value somewhere or I need to call that plugin in Edit Action to see which one is selected?

Comment: Hi Kanchan, please create another question for same and lets discuss there.

Comment: ok... here you go https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/20432/how-to-update-the-values-of-a-selected-row-using-edit-button-action-for-a-cust

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each row is represented by a Child view in the response from Commerce Engine and on the load of page, first row should be selected bu default. To be able to select any other row, each row should have a unique Item Id.
please see image below:

[image]